# Send a lot of parameters to AJAX in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I add my parameters for pass to AJAX using:

```
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('save', 'true');
```

when my parameters become more than 50, send parameters doesn't work and my AJAX file doesn't run. I don't have any problem with less than 50 parameters!

How can I pass more than 50 parameters to AJAX?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "_my AJAX file doesn't run_" What errors do you get?

Comment: When you check on the network tab then check headers what is being sent

Comment: I didn't get any errors

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is that you are maxing some limits.

I would suggest you look into the following php configuration options:

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
max_input_vars
```

You can change the options by configuring your `php.ini` file or use the `ini_set` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) in the top of your file.

If this doesn't help, please provide the ajax response or check your php error logs for any data that can help us understand what the issue might be.

Comment: thank you dear, but your solution didn't solve my problem !

Comment: If you want us to be able to help you, you need to provide some error logs.

Comment: thank you dears. I add one error log in JavaScript and I get my problem. one of my object's id was wrong!